# What is the maximum size for attachment using unix mailx

Tags: size, mailx

I am using RHEL 6.4. I have a script which runs in bash. The script sends an email using the command:

```
mailx -a report.txt "Monthly Report" "business@user.com" < messageBody.html
```

where `report.txt` is a pipe separated text file. The size of this file is unknown; sometimes this file may contain just 10-15 records, on other days it may have millions of records.

Now my questions are:

1. How do I determine what is the maximum file size that can be sent as an attachment?
2. How to change that size?

Comment: That really depends on your mail delivery system. If it is all internal, then you may be able to send very large files. However, if your mail administrator has limited the size of attachments, which is good practice, then it will be whatever limit has been set. You'd be best off asking your mail administrator what that limit is, if any.

Comment: mailx is `MUA`, It's depend on your `MTA`.

Comment: Thank you Warwick and Mohsen, i was able to check with our mail administrator and he asked me to run this command:
`postconf -d | grep message_size`
which provided me the size on the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check maximum size on systems using `postfix` as their mail transport agent, we can use the `postconf` command.

```
postconf -d | grep message_size
```

It will show you the size in bytes.
To change the value, Run

```
postconf -e 'message_size_limit = 20480000'
```

To make the changes effective, restart Postfix afterwards:

```
service postfix restart
```

(or equivalent on your system)